# How can I know whether the connection to Cassandra was lost with the C++ driver?

Tags: c++, networking, cassandra

I'm wondering whether there is a way for me to know whether the connection to all Cassandra nodes was lost by the C++ driver.

My application has a proxy server which connects to Cassandra once and sits there forever. Other services will connect to that proxy server and send requests as required.

That works great, until all the connections to the Cassandra cluster are lost. In that special circumstance, the proxy does not seem to recover...

Is there a way for me to know/detect that all connections were lost and thus attempt a `connect()` again?

Comment: I have the same question. Maybe the best way is to do a request and get an error response from the driver.

Comment: That's kind of my problem... if I do that from my client to whom I have to reply in less than 1 sec... it's not a good thing to have to wait 10 sec. for the default timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation and the best solution is to check the error from the request/query you make to Cassandra. 
I just tested this and if all connections are gone, the driver immediately returns:

> CASS_ERROR_LIB_NO_HOSTS_AVAILABLE

That's the solution I'm going myself with as I couldn't find a better one and actually this one works for me as it doesn't wait for a specific timeout but return immediately.